# JS Simple Image Slider

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css

I'm currently learning some javascript and I've been getting up to scratch with ES6. I have learned the basics and continued to build things that I've wanted to build in Javascript for a long time.

I am looking for someone to review the code, and to hopefully aid me in becoming a better developer in learning from mistakes.

So the image slider is working from an array which is a div with 4 hidden img elements. The is an img element which is being created within the div #image-display id. The JS then swaps the src attribute based off the number within the counter and the key from the array.

The working copy is on codepen: https://codepen.io/syncoed/pen/WmpEQJ

**HTML**

```
    <div id="image-display" class="mx-auto">
        <span id="left">&#10096;</span>
        <span id="right">&#10097;</span>
    </div>

    <div id="img-container">
        <img id="img-size" src="../image-slider/img/image1.jpg" hidden/>
        <img id="img-size" src="../image-slider/img/image2.jpg" hidden/>
        <img id="img-size" src="../image-slider/img/image3.jpg" hidden/>
        <img id="img-size" src="../image-slider/img/image4.jpg" hidden/>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #image-display{
 width:500px;
 height: 100%;
 border: 3px solid orange;
 z-index: -1;
 padding:3;
 margin:0;
}

#img-size{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 z-index: -1;
 margin:0;
 position: relative;
}

/* left arrow */
#left{
 z-index: 0;
 position: fixed;
 left:21.5%;
 top:10%;
 cursor: pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 padding:0;
}


/* right arrow */
 #right{
 z-index: 0;
 position: fixed;
 right:53.5%;
 top: 10%;
 cursor: pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 padding:0;
}


/*Desktop Media Queries*/

@media(min-width: 1573px) {

#right{
    right:35%;
    top: 12%;
}

#left{
    left:35.5%;
    top:12%;
 }
}

@media(min-width: 1613px) {

#right{
    right:35.5%;
    top: 11%;
}

#left{
    left:35.5%;
    top:11%;
 }
}

@media(min-width: 1140px) {

#right{
    right:37.5%;
    top: 11%;
}

#left{
    left:37.5%;
    top:11%;
 }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
 const imgDisplay = document.querySelector('#image-display');
 const allImages = document.querySelector('#img-container');

 //gets all images
 let all = allImages.querySelectorAll('img');

var imageContainer = document.querySelector('.selector');
let counter = 0;
var newImg = document.createElement('img');
newImg.setAttribute('id', 'img-size');

newImg.setAttribute('src', all[0].src);
imgDisplay.appendChild(newImg);

let imageSelected = all[counter];



imgDisplay.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  if (counter == all.length - 1 && e.target.id == "right") {

    newImg.setAttribute('src', all[0].src);
    counter = 0;

 } else if (counter == 0 && e.target.id == 'left') {

    counter = all.length - 1;
    newImg.setAttribute('src', all[counter].src);

 } else {

    if (e.target.tagName == 'SPAN' && e.target.id == 'right') {
        counter++;

        newImg.setAttribute('src', all[counter].src);
    }

    if (e.target.tagName == 'SPAN' && e.target.id == 'left') {

        counter--;
        newImg.setAttribute('src', all[counter].src);

    }
 }



});
```

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation:

If you're going to take the source of an image and set it to another image, why even bother having those images as HTML? It would be *much* simpler to simply store the image urls in an array like so:

```
const imageUrls = [
  "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E6CYI3Xb1tQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Dragon_Ball_Z_Logo.png",
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDWVk-v3DR5j0pHabogu6i3n1KLhqJWNd-Z54qevISiCoHKF88",
  "https://media.comicbook.com/2017/02/vegeta-dragon-ball-z-235088-1280x0.png"
];
```

Secondly, you're using a `counter` variable and an `imageSelected` variable... but their end goal is the same thing. Stick with the `counter`.

You're spending a lot of time writing conditions, why not use % (modulo) to determine which is the next image.

When the right button is clicked simply do:

```
counter = (counter + 1) % imageUrls.length
```

This way, once you get to the last image (counter = 3) and wish to go to the next one, then `(counter + 1) = (3+1) = (4)`. So the new position is 4 however the imageUrl length is 4.. and `4 % 4 = 0`. So, it's an easy solution to reset the counter to 0 when it gets to the end of the image url list.

However, this doesn't work when you wish to go left. Because module doesn't work on negative numbers. To solve this do the following.

```
counter = (counter + -1 + imageUrls.length) % imageUrls.length
```

Now, to figure out if it's `1` or `-1` and to avoid setting a condition for it, we're going to store those values in the [`data attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) in the left and right HTML elements like so:

```
<span data-direction="1" id="left">&#10096;</span>
<span data-direction="-1" id="right">&#10097;</span>
```

Then simply to access them in the event callback:

```
Number(this.dataset.direction) //returns a string so reason why use Number to convert it.
```

Now, all there is left to do is to complete the formula.

```
counter = (counter + Number(this.dataset.direction) + imageUrls.length) % imageUrls.length;
```

Avoid setting the onclick function to a container and actually set it to the elements that need to be clicked.

```
imgDisplay.querySelectorAll("#left, #right").forEach(element=>{
  //first time this is called element = left
  //second time this is called element = second
  //for each element add an event listener.
});
```

### Solution:

```
const imageUrls = [
  "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E6CYI3Xb1tQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Dragon_Ball_Z_Logo.png",
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDWVk-v3DR5j0pHabogu6i3n1KLhqJWNd-Z54qevISiCoHKF88",
  "https://media.comicbook.com/2017/02/vegeta-dragon-ball-z-235088-1280x0.png"
];

const imgDisplay = document.getElementById('image-display');


let counter = 0;
const img = new Image();
img.src = imageUrls[counter];
imgDisplay.appendChild(img);

imgDisplay.querySelectorAll("#left, #right").forEach(element=>{
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      counter = (counter + Number(this.dataset.direction) + imageUrls.length) % imageUrls.length;
      img.src = imageUrls[counter];
  });
});
```

### Working Example:

```js
const imageUrls = [
  "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E6CYI3Xb1tQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Dragon_Ball_Z_Logo.png",
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDWVk-v3DR5j0pHabogu6i3n1KLhqJWNd-Z54qevISiCoHKF88",
  "https://media.comicbook.com/2017/02/vegeta-dragon-ball-z-235088-1280x0.png"
];

const imgDisplay = document.getElementById('image-display');


let counter = 0;
const img = new Image();
img.src = imageUrls[counter];
imgDisplay.appendChild(img);

imgDisplay.querySelectorAll("#left, #right").forEach(element=>{
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      counter = (counter + Number(this.dataset.direction) + imageUrls.length) % imageUrls.length;
      img.src = imageUrls[counter];
  });
});
```

```css
#image-display {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 3;
  margin: 0;
}

#img-size {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}


/* left arrow */

#left {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 21.5%;
  top: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
}


/* right arrow */

#right {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 53.5%;
  top: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
}


/*Desktop Media Queries*/

@media(min-width: 1573px) {
  #right {
    right: 35%;
    top: 12%;
  }
  #left {
    left: 35.5%;
    top: 12%;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1613px) {
  #right {
    right: 35.5%;
    top: 11%;
  }
  #left {
    left: 35.5%;
    top: 11%;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1140px) {
  #right {
    right: 37.5%;
    top: 11%;
  }
  #left {
    left: 37.5%;
    top: 11%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div id="image-display" class="mx-auto">
      <!-- <img id="img-size" class="selector" /> -->
      <span data-direction="1" id="left">&#10096;</span>
      <span data-direction="-1" id="right">&#10097;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for reviewing, there was a lot of room to refactor the code, but this was simply basic for what I have learned in JS at the moment and using ES6. I'm hoping to use this within a latest project of mine, where the user simply uploads pictures, which this part is built :). I will review your solution and attempt to look into the other approach. Greatly appreciated.